# Condition based scraping using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape the dates and the respectives news headlines/articles for a period of 6days- like when the python script runs today,it should scrape headlines/articles from today(10th August) to 4th August.
I am able to scrape the dates and headlines/urls for all dates as of now from [here](https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/).
here is the code for the same

```
    websites = ['https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/']
    for spirits in websites:
        browser.get(spirits)
        time.sleep(1)

        news_links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="archivewrapper"]/div/div[2]/h3')
        n_links = [ele.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href') for ele in news_links]
        dates = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="archivewrapper"]/div/div[2]/small')
        n_dates = [ele.text for ele in dates]
        print(n_links)
        print(n_dates)
```

But how do I scrape for a period for last 6days from today? Is there an idea?

Comment: Use ```datetime``` module.

Comment: @Ram : I thought about that as well, but the dates mentioned on the website articles are all in text format. so if the threshold to 6 and then datetime.today()- from website is what I thought...but..idk.

Comment: Then extract the date from that string.

Answer (score 1):

See the page 2 url is

```
https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/page/2/
```

which basically means, that for next iteration you would need to add `/page/2/` in URL.

you can have a websites list as :

```
websites = ['https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/', 'https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/page/2/', 'https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/page/3/']
```

and so on, to achieve this.

or you can do this programmatically as well :-

```
page_number = 1
websites = ['https://www.thespiritsbusiness.com/tag/rum/']
for spirits in websites:
        browser.get(spirits + f"page/{page_number}/")
        page_number = page_number + 1
```

Comment: Hi cruise, thanks for your immediate response, on page 2 however the headlines which are having dates go way beyond the threshold- ie of 6days. Suppose I want to run the script today on 10th August, then-> the script should give me a result of urls from 4th August,5th August till 10th August.

Comment: I see it's going beyond on page 1 itself, I see this `May 20th, 2021` on page 1

Comment: yeah.. And I only want to scrape for the last 6 days